# API for accessing CTS and DSR signals of serial port

Tags: c++, refactoring, windows, api-design, readability

I'm trying to improve another abstraction of the serial port. The project involved often needs to check one of the single control signals CTS and DSR. This is currently done by a call to `GetCommModemStatus`, that's very wordy: a variable is needed and a binary AND operation, `GetComModemStatus` can also fail (this is more theoretically, but where to check this otherwise...)

I wish to expand the "abstraction" in question by getters for CTS and DSR. And I need help in the decision to make them return `bool` or `int` and if the prefix `get` wouldn't make the resulting code harder to read? Should I use full capitalization?

Here follow some examples of code that would use the new API:

1) with prefix `get` and boolean result

```
if (sp.getCts()) {
    // CTS is ON
}

if (!sp.getCts()) {
    // CTS is OFF, in my eyes this looks like getting CTS has failed
}
```

2) no `get` prefix with integer result

```
if (sp.Cts()==1) {
    // CTS is ON
}

if (sp.Cts()==0) {
    // CTS is OFF
}
```

3) with capitalized CTS (again, no `get` with `bool` result)

```
if (sp.CTS()) {
    // CTS is ON
}

if (!sp.CTS()) {
    // CTS is OFF
}
```

...this is just to illustrate what I tried in mind; maybe there is even a better solution I left out?